# C# MySql Sometimes insert executed twice or not executed

Tags: c#, mysql

I have to insert data to 3 tables in my MySql let say it was table1, table2 and table3 
my problem is sometimes insert query for table2 is executed twice and sometimes it's not executed 
Here is my code :

```
string Query = @"insert into table1(SellCode, SellDate, SellType, Discount, BuyerCode) 
                                    values (@SellCode, @SellDate, @SellType, @Discount, @BuyerCode)";


            using (MySqlConnection conExpDB = new MySqlConnection(ConString))
            using (MySqlCommand cmdExpDB = new MySqlCommand(Query, conExpDB))
            {
                try
                {
                    conExpDB.Open();
                    cmdExpDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SellCode", SellCode);
                    cmdExpDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SellDate", DateTime.Now);
                    cmdExpDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SellType", "Retail");
                    cmdExpDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Discount", txtDiscount.Text);
                    cmdExpDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BuyerCode", "1");


                    int rowsUpdated = cmdExpDB.ExecuteNonQuery();


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }//end try

            }//end using



            string QueryB = @"insert into table2(PaymentCode, PaymentAmount, 
                                    SellCode, PaymentDate) 
                                    values (@PaymentCode, @PaymentAmount, @SellCode, @PaymentDate)";


            using (MySqlConnection conExpDB = new MySqlConnection(ConString))
            using (MySqlCommand cmdExpDB = new MySqlCommand(QueryB, conExpDB))
            {
                try
                {
                    conExpDB.Open();
                    cmdExpDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PaymentCode", paymentcode);
                    cmdExpDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PaymentAmount", PaymentAmount);
                    cmdExpDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SellCode", SellCode);
                    cmdExpDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PaymentDate", DateTime.Now);


                    int rowsUpdated = cmdExpDB.ExecuteNonQuery();


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }//end try

            }//end using

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in GridView.Rows)
            {
                string QueryDetail = @"insert into table3(SellDetailCode, SellCode, 
                                    ItemCode, Qty, 
                                    Price) 
                                    values (@SellDetailCode, @SellCode, @ItemCode, @Qty, 
                                    @Price)";

                using (MySqlConnection conExpDB = new MySqlConnection(ConString))
                using (MySqlCommand cmdExpDB = new MySqlCommand(QueryDetail, conExpDB))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        conExpDB.Open();


                        cmdExpDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SellDetailCode", SellDetailCode);
                        cmdExpDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SellCode", SellCode);
                        cmdExpDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemCode", ItemCode);
                        cmdExpDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", Qty);
                        cmdExpDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price", Price);

                        int rowsUpdated = cmdExpDB.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }//end try
                }//end using
            }//end foreach
```

Is there any effective method to detect the queries are inserted twice or not executed? Or is there any problem with my queries? 
Because it's happened very rare it's difficult for me fixed this error

Comment: Have you tried inspecting or logging the return values of ExecuteNonQuery?

"For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command." (source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx)

And for the case of multiple inserts, are you running these queries on an event, which, may be, is getting triggered twice? Just a thought

Comment: i group this query into "private void savTransaction", but only table2 sometimes execute twice or sometimes not executed

Comment: Yes but whose calling savTransaction and when, that might have been of relevance here.

Comment: I've already overlook my code again savTransaction only execute when push the save button, maybe i'll try to inspecting the return values first just like your suggestion